# Select MAX within multiple inner join

Tags: sql

I want to select max values related to query, but all results are coming. Any idea ?

QUERY

```
SELECT MAXRecID,MAXSetID,MAXRID,PreReifiedValue,ComplianceState
FROM v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus as A
INNER JOIN v_CIRules as B
ON B.CI_ID = A.CI_ID
INNER JOIN v_R_System  as C
ON C.ResourceID = A.ItemKey
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT PreReifiedValue,setting_CI_ID,
MAX(RecordID) AS MAXRecID,
MAX(SettingID) AS MAXSetID,
MAX(RuleID) AS MAXRID
FROM CI_CurrentRuleDetail
GROUP BY PreReifiedValue,Setting_CI_ID,instancedata) AS D ON D.Setting_CI_ID = A.CI_ID
GROUP by MAXRecID,MAXSetID,MAXRID,PreReifiedValue,rulename,ComplianceState
```

Results

```
MAXRecID            MAXSetID    MAXRID  PreReifiedValue ComplianceState
72057594038117564   16780566    16780622    10                2
72057594038117565   16780570    16780620     0                2
```

Comment: May be because you have three columns in Group by in inner query but you have joined only one column. Either remove the other two columns in Group by or add the missing join predicates. Add sample data and expected result

Comment: Have you tried with `SELECT TOP (1) MAXRecID,MAXSetID ....` ?

Comment: If your untagged DBMS (hint hint) supports it, look into the use of `row_number()`

Comment: How to use TOP 1 Within this query ;

SELECT PreReifiedValue,setting_CI_ID,
MAX(RecordID) AS MAXRecID,
MAX(SettingID) AS MAXSetID,
MAX(RuleID) AS MAXRID

Comment: None of is worked.